# Not writing enough lines to output file

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file 'purchases.txt' which has a repeating city **Fort Worth**.
I want to write each line from each city into an output file based on the city name (eg. Fort Worth.txt)

**purchases.txt**

```
2012-01-01  09:00   San Jose    Men's Clothing  214.05  Amex
2012-01-01  09:00   Fort Worth  Women's Clothing    153.57  Visa
2012-01-01  09:00   San Diego   Music   66.08   Cash
2012-01-01  09:00   Pittsburgh  Pet Supplies    493.51  Discover
2012-01-01  09:00   Omaha   Children's Clothing 235.63  MasterCard
2012-01-01  09:00   Stockton    Men's Clothing  247.18  MasterCard
2012-01-01  09:00   Austin  Cameras 379.6   Visa
2012-01-01  09:00   New York    Consumer Electronics    296.8   Cash
2012-01-01  09:00   Corpus Christi  Toys    25.38   Discover
2012-01-01  09:00   Fort Worth  Toys    213.88  Visa
```

**Main code**

```
with open('purchases.txt') as input:    

      for line in input:

         city=line.split('\t')[2]

         with open('%s.txt' %city, 'w') as output:

            output.write(line)
```

It works almost perfectly but why is it that Fort Worth.txt only has 1 line of text instead of 2? How do I solve this?

**My Fort Worth.txt**

```
2012-01-01  09:00   Fort Worth  Toys    213.88  Visa
```

**Desired Fort Worth.txt**

```
2012-01-01  09:00   Fort Worth  Women's Clothing    153.57  Visa
2012-01-01  09:00   Fort Worth  Toys    213.88  Visa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always collect **all** the information in a `defaultdict` first:

```
from collections import defaultdict

outputs = defaultdict(list)
with open('purchases.txt') as input:    

      for line in input:

         city = line.split('\t')[2]
         outputs[city].append(line)

for city,lines in outputs.items()
     with open('%s.txt' %city, 'w') as output:
         for line in lines:
            output.write(line)
```

Now you open the files once and write all the collected lines in one go.

This does assume that the file `purchases.txt` is not too large that its contents will overflow main memory.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using "w" when trying to write the file. Use **"a"** to append content to a file

Change

```
with open('%s.txt' %city, 'w') as output:
```

to

```
with open('%s.txt' %city, 'a') as output:
```

Comment: More on file modes in python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Is there a way to still use 'w' without using 'a' to get the 2 lines of text in Fort Worth.txt? Because if I keep on running the code, it will just keep on appending to all 9 files which isn't what I really want.

Comment: unfortunately no. using "w" initialize the file from the start. only using "a" can you append content to a file.

Comment: You probably need to change the logic of the script to have your desired output of having only Fort Worth.txt with 2 lines